compiling pytorch encounter error ou found a build system error: AVX512F, AVX512DQ, AVX512VL ' 'is defined
"When I encounter this error while compiling PyTorch: error: #error ( 'You found a build system error: AVX512F, AVX512DQ, AVX512VL ' 'is defined (via e.g. -mavx512f, -mavx512dq, and -mavx512vl) ' 'but CAFFE2_PERF_WITH_AVX512 is not defined.');"

At /home/whyin/Dis_pnp/PNP/caffe2/aten/src/ATen/cpu/vec256/avx512/vec256_avx512f.cc:18, the error message is:


error: #error ("You found a build system error: AVX512F, AVX512VL, and -mavx512" " but >CAFFE2_PERF_WITH_AVX512 is not defined.");

This indicates that _AVX512F_, _AVX512VL_, and -mavx512 are detected in the build system, but CAFFE2_PERF_WITH_AVX512 is not defined.

At /home/whyin/Dis_pnp/PNP/caffe2/CMakeFiles/Caffe2_perfkernels_avx.dir/build.make:629/2386, the build of Caffe2's performance kernels (Caffe2_perfkernels_avx) fails.

what i do :
git clone pytorch and python setup.py then I encouter this problem.
my env is:

cuda 12.1
cmake 3.22
gcc 11.0

